# SharePoint and Reverse Proxy

Tags: sharepoint

I've read it is wise to use a reverse proxy in front of a SharePoint installation that has a public site on it.
If so, any recommendations on which product, doesn't Microsoft have a reverse proxy product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical Microsoft solution would involve publish SharePoint with Microsoft ISA; however, the new product out there is branded under the Forefront product line as the Forefront Unified Access Gateway (UAG).

Check out [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd861393.aspx) on Technet for reasons why you would publish SharePoint with UAG.

Comment: is UAG a microsoft product?

Comment: Yes it is.  Forefront is Microsoft's security product line.